# Why do the Shot annotations return in RPC but are not present in json file on google storage?

Tags: python, video-intelligence-api

I can get the shot annotations when I use the rpc from the sample code:

```
features = [
    enums.Feature.LABEL_DETECTION,
    enums.Feature.SHOT_CHANGE_DETECTION
]
operation = video_client.annotate_video(path, features=features, output_uri=json_file)
result = operation.result(timeout=90)

for i, shot in enumerate(result.annotation_results[0].shot_annotations):
    start_time = (shot.start_time_offset.seconds +
                  shot.start_time_offset.nanos / 1e9)
    end_time = (shot.end_time_offset.seconds +
                shot.end_time_offset.nanos / 1e9)
    print('\tShot {}: {} to {}'.format(i, start_time, end_time))
```

However the json file created by `annotate_video()` and written to the GS bucket only includes values for the keys `segment_label_annotations` and `shot_label_annotations`. The `shot_annotations` key is an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

An empty result for shot_annotations might be caused by the client library. Please make sure to use the [official Google Cloud examples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/tree/f2c49c8b07a82260d29de408b5d3c9d25de924ce/videointelligence). It is also recommended, in the beginning, to go through the Cloud Video Intelligence API [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/quickstart) and [Tutorials](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/tutorials).

Also make sure that the [latest version of the API](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/videointelligence/index.html) is called and use the v1p1beta1 endpoint that includes more functionalities.

You can also first test the [Google Cloud video samples](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/) to exclude there is a video format compatibility issue.